# Circular Linked List implementating a Deque resulting in Infinite Loop

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

```
    private class LinkedList<T> {

    private int size;
    private Node sentinel;

    public LinkedList() {

        sentinel = new Node(null, null, null);
        size = 0;
    }


        public void addFirst(T data) {

        Node newNode = new Node(data, sentinel, sentinel.next);
        sentinel.next = newNode;

        if (newNode.next == null){
            sentinel.prev = newNode;
            newNode.next = sentinel;  //got in infinite loop here
        }


    }
```

I am working through Josh Hug's CS 61B work on implementing a deque.  I got in infinite loop somehow with the code `node.next = sentinel`.  This deque is implemented by a circular linked list.  Any idea why this line of code get me in infinite loop?

Comment: Can you post the Node class as well

Comment: Unable to understand the scenario without Node class.

Comment: In order to have an _infinite_ loop, you first have to have an **actual loop**.  Clearly, `node.next = sentinel;` is not a loop by itself, nor is it enclosed in any loop.   Please show the actual code that is looping infinitely and describe the circumstances which lead up that infinite loop.

Comment: why did you put the pointer reassignments into node constructor? it should be a part of list's method, not node constructor